# ggvis for PCA with vector loadings?

Tags: r, pca, ggvis, ggbiplot

A few years back, [Chitrasen](https://github.com/chitcode/assignment) managed to use `ggvis` for PCA - with the significantly higher interactivity available for `ggvis` I really want to use it going forward.  However, I'm unable to locate any information outside of Chitrasen's code for making this a reality.

While the model in the link above provides accurately plotted points and scale, vector loading arrows and variable names are missing.  I think this must be the result of there not being any equivalent to `geom_segment` for `ggvis` yet.

I've tried splicing in the relevant bits of code from `ggbiplot` to skirt the issue:

```
nobs.factor <- sqrt(pcobj$n.obs)
d <- pcobj$sdev
u <- sweep(pcobj$scores, 2, 1/(d * nobs.factor), FUN = "*")
v <- pcobj$loadings
df.u <- as.data.frame(sweep(u[, 1:2], 2, d[1:2]^1,
                            FUN = "*"))
v <- sweep(v, 2, d^1, FUN = "*")
df.v <- as.data.frame(v[, 1:2])
names(df.u) <- c("xvar", "yvar")
names(df.v) <- names(df.u)
df.u <- df.u * nobs.factor
r <- sqrt(qchisq(0.69, df = 2)) * prod(colMeans(df.u^2))^(1/4)
v.scale <- rowSums(v^2)
df.v <- r * df.v/sqrt(max(v.scale))
df.v$angle <- with(df.v, (180/pi) * atan(yvar/xvar))
df.v$hjust = with(df.v, (1 - 1.5 * sign(xvar))/2)
theta <- c(seq(-pi, pi, length = 50), seq(pi, -pi,
                                          length = 50))
circle <- data.frame(xvar = r * cos(theta), yvar = r *
                       sin(theta))
```

The above code creates the information needed for the vector loadings, which is then passed to the code below:

```
g <- g + geom_segment(data = df.v, aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = xvar, yend = yvar), 
arrow = arrow(length = unit(1/2,"picas")), 
color = color, linetype = linetype, alpha = alpha_arrow)
```

However, I keep coming back to the same brick wall of not being able to create individual segments.  Intuitively, it should be possible since `ggbiplot` is taking information from a `princomp` object, which is exactly what Chitrasen's model is using as well.  I know you can make some lines in `ggvis` using `layer_lines` and `layer_paths`, but I've as yet been unable to get these to radiate from the x and y zero point.

I'm wondering if anyone out there has any advice on how to proceed/if it's even possible with current `ggvis` capabilities?  The potential of tooltips and slider bars with full-blown PCA has me salivating....

Comment: can you share your data?

Comment: There isn't really any data to speak of - I literally plugged the above code into the `ggvis` PCA function, and then hit the end and realized none of the tinkering would do any good because all the information was still being fed into a `geom_segment`.  That's where I'm stuck, and have no idea where to to go from.